# How to create large size array(like 6 billion) in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create a large size array(about 80000*80000)

I tried

```
int *bigarray = new int[80000*80000];
```

but it gave me the error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc

And the thing I want to do is to create a social network's edge matrix.

Can anyone tell me how to create a large size array or any other methods to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: 6 billion (Giga) int(s) are 51 Gigabytes (X8) of RAM on Win X64.

Comment: Look up Sparse Matrix libraries.

Comment: @AmitG. So what? You can certainly put that much of RAM (and more) into a single motherboard, it's not that exotic these days.

Comment: @zett42 It's not exotic, it's expensive. & you will be unable to run you target on other computers, because most of them have 32GB at the most. It might be possible to manage the situation in a more common way, that can be run on any mid-range computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can stop the overflow warning by not using `int`, use `unsigned long long` - add `ULL` to the ends of your literal numbers:

```
auto arr = new int[80000ULL * 80000ULL];
```

I would recommend using a `std::vector` rather than a raw dynamic array:

```
auto vec = std::vector<int>(80000ULL * 80000ULL);
```

Your `std::bad_alloc` means you don't have enough memory....

> And the thing I want to do is to create a social network's edge matrix.

You can look into using a "sparse matrix". If most of the locations in your array are empty you can use a data structure that records only the occupied cells' values.

A crude example would be to use a `std::map<std::size_t, std::map<std::size_t, int>>` but there are some dedicated libraries out there that will do a better job.

For example the [Eigen Library](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/). (props @yar)